# Unable to set proper fonts format by using angular 7 structure. Below is my code which will exlplain exact problem

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015

1. All fonts files are in assets folder as common files as shown in sreenshot
   [image]
2. I have gave link of these files in index.html which main html files in angular structure
3. html file which have link of fonts folder.

[image]

4. Fonts are not in proper format as shown below

[image]

5. I am unable to understand where exact is problem problem,I am not getting proper fonts as per my requirement.

Comment: why is your question title about font loading then the code you provide is about scrolling to the top of the page? can you please clarify what the issue is?

Comment: Did you apply the fonts to the `body`?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon  my title is about fonts,beacuse I am not getting proper fonts in my browser.all fonts files are in assets folder from where i am getting and some are directly getting from goolge api. when I run the project in browser, I don,t get any exception or error. but fonts doest not come as per my requirement                                                                                               I am giving link these fonts files in index.html file. which code file have atteched. is there proper way to give link of fonts file by using angular sturcture?

Comment: @Rust  yes I had apply the fonts to the body

Answer (score 1):

import font in style.css file. 
As

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  src: url('assets/fonts/segoeui.eot');
  src: url('assets/fonts/segoeui.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), url('assets/fonts/segoeui.woff2') format('woff2'), url('assets/fonts/segoeui.woff') format('woff'), url('assets/fonts/segoeui.ttf') format('truetype'), url('assets/fonts/segoeui.svg#segoeui') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: problem is still same

Comment: have you add path of style.css file to a angular.json file?